# Random Algorithm with adjustable probability

Tags: algorithm, random

I'm searching for an algorithm (no matter what programming language, maybe Pseudo-code?) where you get a random number with different probability's.

For example:

> A random Generator, which simulates a dice where the chance for a '6'
>   is 50% and for the other 5 numbers it's 10%.

The algorithm should be scalable, because this is my exact problem:

> I have a array (or database) of elements, from which i want to
>   select 1 random element. But each element should have a different
>   probability to be selected. So my idea is that every element get a
>   number. And this number divided by the sum of all numbers results the
>   chance for the number to be randomly selected.

Anybody know a good programming language (or library) for this problem?
The best solution would be a good SQL Query which delivers 1 random entry.
But i would also be happy with every hint or attempt in an other programming language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple algorithm to achieve it is:

1. Create an auexillary array where `sum[i] = p1 + p2 + ... + pi`. This is done only once.
2. When you draw a number, draw a number `r` with uniform distribution over `[0,sum[n])`, and binary search for the first number **higher** than the uniformly distributed random number. It can be done using [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) efficiently.

It is easy to see that indeed the probability for `r` to lay in a certain range `[sum[i-1],sum[i])`, is indeed `sum[i]-sum[i-1] = pi`

(In the above, we regard `sum[-1]=0`, for completeness)

---

For your cube example:

You have:

```
p1=p2=....=p5 = 0.1
p6 = 0.5
```

First, calculate `sum` array:

```
sum[1] = 0.1
sum[2] = 0.2
sum[3] = 0.3
sum[4] = 0.4
sum[5] = 0.5
sum[6] = 1
```

Then, each time you need to draw a number: Draw a random number `r` in `[0,1)`, and choose the number closest to it, for example:

```
r1 = 0.45 -> element = 4
r2 = 0.8 -> element = 6
r3 = 0.1 -> element = 2
r4 = 0.09 -> element = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative answer.  Your example was in percentages, so set up an array with 100 slots.  A 6 is 50%, so put 6 in 50 of the slots.  1 to 5 are at 10% each, so put 1 in 10 slots, 2 in 10 slots etc. until you have filled all 100 slots in the array.  Now pick one of the slots at random using a uniform distribution in [0, 99] or [1, 100] depending on the language you are using.

The contents of the selected array slot will give you the distribution you want.

ETA: On second thoughts, you don't actually need the array, just use cumulative probabilities to emulate the array:

```
r = rand(100) // In range 0 -> 99 inclusive.

if (r < 50) return 6;  // Up to 50% returns a 6.
if (r < 60) return 1;  // Between 50% and 60% returns a 1.
if (r < 70) return 2;  // Between 60% and 70% returns a 2.
etc.
```

You already know what numbers are in what slots, so just use cumulative probabilities to pick a virtual slot: 50; 50 + 10; 50 + 10 + 10; ...

Be careful of edge cases and whether your RNG is 0 -> 99 or 1 -> 100.

Comment: Thanks, this would work for my easy example well and i had this idea too.
But this won't work, if i don't know how many elements i will have or which probability they will have.
Your second thought is really similar to the solution from amit.
But thanks as well!